# OpenCL __constant vs #define

Tags: opencl

I have quite a number of constants that govern memory allocations, number of loop iterations, etc. in my OpenCL kernel. Is it faster to use global __constants or #defines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same rules as for a "normal" C compiler apply to an OpenCL compiler: A `#define` is replaced with the value *before* actual compilation, thus they are baked into the kernel.

Per definition, a `__constant` variable is allocated in the global memory and must be transferred before use. This is slower than using a `#define`d literal. However, the GPU architectures from NVIDIA and AMD cache these values and are faster to read than ordinary global memory.

End of story and my personal advice: Use `#defines` for constant values as well as "magic" numbers and `__constant` memory for larger fast but read-only memory blocks (e.g. lookup tables).

Comment: I agree with what you say, except for the fact that constant memory must be transferred. I never managed to do this. For me the only way to use constant memory was to define values of a large constant array using #define...

Comment: You create a constant memory buffer just like any other memory buffer but with the `CL_MEM_READ_ONLY` flag set. To transfer it, you use the `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` flag or copy as usual with `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`.

Comment: If you are using __constant buffer remember to check  the Device Info property CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE  to get the max  constant buffer size.

Comment: @matthias, this did not work for me. The kernel executed with a buffer created with CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, was significantly slower compared to a __constant array defined in the source...
As if it did not go into the cached memory.

Comment: And you also used the `__constant` specifier for the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

define works the same way as in C. An exception to this is all versions before AMD APP SDK v2.8 (without OpenCL 1.2 support).

__Constant is the cahched memory space. Please do read more information on memory layout in OpenCL.

__global is the total memory of the GPU, visible for all threads.

__local is the local memory of the GPU, visible by only threads inside the block.

__constant is the cached memory which is much faster then global but limited, so use it only where required.

__private is the private memory of the GPU, visible by each individual threads only.

Note: Threads, I mean processing elements.